# Can't edit soap envelope

Tags: services

I'm trying to test SOAP webservices using the [webservice client module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient) but I can't edit the datatype parameter which is set by default to arg0.

I've changed it to what is shown in the picture below but still the  soap request has that parameter set as arg0
       [image]

[image]

**EDIT:**

Looking around I found the function `drupal_get_form($form_id)` which sets the arguments in the forms_state array, `$form_state['build_info']['args'] = $args`, using `func_get_args()` which gets a copy of the current user-defined function's argument list.

Not sure if that's the function which is causing me this problem but I really don't get why that  tag is wrong but the others are all correct. 
I really don't know what to do as I've cleared the cache and ran cron already.

**EDIT**
 I found the class responsible of making the soap call, wsclient_soap.module, I modified the call function so as to have my own arguments but still the problem remains.

```
  public function call($operation) {
  $client = $this->client();
  $testargs= array( 
ModelCRUDRequest => array(
    ModelCRUD=>array(
    serviceType=>"GetProductList",
    TableName=>"",
    RecordID=>"",
    RecordIDVarialbe=>"",
    Filter=>"",
    Action=>"Read",
    DataRow=>array(
      field=>array(
        val=>"",
        lookup=>array(
          lv=>array(
           val=>"",key=>""
                    )//endlv array
                      ),//endlookuup array
        type=>"",
        column=>"",
        lval=>"",
        disp=>"",
        edit=>"",
        error=>"",
        errorval=>""
                  )//end field array

                       )//end data row array

                     ),//end ModelCRUD 
ADLoginRequest=> array(
  user=>"GardenUser",
  pass=>"GardenUser",
  lang=>"192",
  ClientID=>"11",
  RoleID=>"103",
  OrgID=>"11",
  WarehouseID=>"103",
  stage =>"0"        )//endADLoginRequest
    )//endModelCrudRequest
    );


try {
  $response = $client->__soapCall($operation, $testargs);
  return $response;
}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
  throw new WSClientException('Error invoking the SOAP service %name, operation %operation: %error', array('%name' => $this->service->label, '%operation' => $operation, '%error' => $e->getMessage()));
}
  }
 }
```

I think it has to do with the [WSDL document](https://gist.github.com/Leyonce/5bbc7d698cba33b73385)

```
-<wsdl:message name="queryData"><wsdl:part element="tns:ModelCRUDRequest" name="arg0">
-</wsdl:part></wsdl:message>
```

Can someone please help me out?